# How do I detect if the user is "idle" with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, mouse

I'm developing a "real-time" web application which sends AJAX requests to the server every 10 seconds. Obviously this is very bandwidth-intensive and I would like to know if there's any solution to this.

My idea is checking if the user doesn't move his mouse for X seconds. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're searching for this: https://github.com/jasonmcleod/jquery.idle

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Simple and effective. Thanks!

Comment: jquery.idle only watches for mousemove events. So if you are content on labeling a user as idle simply because they haven't moved the mouse then this should work fine for you. However, you may want to also watch for other events such as keyboard input.

Comment: Also, this isn't going to work for touch interfaces, since they don't fire mouse events.

Answer (score 15):

You may want to listen for some or all of the following events:

mouseMove, mouseClick, mouseUp, mouseDown, keyDown, keyUp, keyPress

set a timer to go off after some duration of idleness (60 seconds?) and that will turn off your switch make sure you check your switch before your ajax requests.

Ideally you'll exponentially throttle your ajax calls to some low value the longer a user remains idle.

```
$(window).bind('mousemove click mouseup mousedown keydown keypress keyup submit change mouseenter scroll resize dblclick', someEvent);
var active = true,
  delay = 60000,
  timer = null;

function someEvent(e)
{
  active = true;
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function(t){
    active = false;
  }, delay);
}
```

Comment: Really liked your ideas. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielS, I was reviewing some of my earliest answers (this is one of them) to see what sorts of improvements I could make, and I was just making a note to add information about [debouncing](http://unscriptable.com/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/) to this answer because it's appropriate.

Comment: That's a really interesting article.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way: http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=2700
And using Jquery : http://www.bedroomlan.org/coding/detecting-%E2%80%98idle%E2%80%99-and-%E2%80%98away%E2%80%99-timeouts-javascript