# Redirect to login if user inactive zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session, zend-layout

I want to redirect to login page if user is inactive for 30 minutes.

Where to write the code and how? 
 I have layout.phtml.  Is it the right place to check session expired and redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check user inactivity with Javascript. If you want to check this in all pages of the site, layout.phtml is the right place to insert the Javascript. Check SO threads like this -  [How do i detect if the user is "idle" with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102185/how-do-i-detect-if-the-user-is-idle-with-javascript)  - for sample scripts.

Comment: Thankz for your reply. 

But actually I want to do it with PHP. Because i want to clear Zend_Session and Zend_Auth and finally redirect to login form.   Is there any way ?

Comment: Yes, you can. Use a good JS library to detect idle time. Once you detect idle time for an amount of time, redirect the user to logout page. You can clear session, auth etc in the logout action.

Comment: It works perfectly.  I had detect idle time using jquery and redirect to logout function and there I clear sessions and redirect to login page.  Thank u..