# How do I get the last page load a user went through so I can check if the user is 'Away" or "Offline"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to work on a status attribute for users for when they are online, offline, or away but the away one is throwing me off. I have the online set when the user logs in and the offline set when the user clicks logout. But how do I check when a user has been sitting on a page for a while so I can set the status attribute to away? According to other questions you can check your updated_at timestamp but I don't think you can because my doesn't update after each page load.

Comment: One idea is to use JavaScript to check the coords of their cursor at specified intervals, then fire off an AJAX request if they've been idle for a while. In fact, I believe there is a plugin. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102185/how-do-i-detect-if-the-user-is-idle-with-javascript

Comment: With that plugin would my selector be the entire html page or how else would I do it?

Comment: Also, how would I add this plugin to my rails project. Is it just a simple copy and paste into my assets folder?

Comment: I haven't actually used the library so I couldn't be sure. You'll have to read the documentation. You can add it to your project by placing it in your `vendor` directory under your javascript assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at rails [instrumentation API](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_instrumentation.html). You can capture all the user actions using the instrumentation API. If there are no actions from the user in past x minutes and the user is not logged out, then your user is idle/away.

Instrumentation will be very helpful to analyse trends, preferences etc.

For eg: You can find out the action that had the most number of hits